# How to Show Different Sidebars on Specific Pages?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, sidebar

I'm making a blog where only on specific pages I want to show different sidebar, I will add some widgets to those sidebar, which I don't want to show in default sidebar.

I've found [a coding method to do this](http://dev.studiopress.com/display-alternate-sidebar.htm), but I would like to use a plugin, and not edit code myself.

I need to give the control of adding/removing sidebar/widgets in client hands.

So is there any plug-in to do this easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A client of mine recently used a plug-in similar to [Widget Context](http://www.techyard.net/control-wordpress-widget-visibility-widget-context-plugin/) to accomplish this.

Rather than create different *sidebars* you just define what *contexts* you want your widgets to show up in.  So if you have a set of widgets you want to show up on a specific page, you mark them to only show up on that page.  But it allows you to continue using widgets that show up on every page/post if you want.

The convenience of this plug-in is that you don't have to code anything, and it's got a fairly intuitive UI you can put in the hands of your own clients.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer [widget logic](http://freakytrigger.co.uk/wordpress-setup/) over widget context. However, I can't recall the reason of it.

Comment: I use Widget Logic as well. As I remember difference is this one has less UI and so more manual conditionals (which is fine for my needs).

Comment: I tried both and found and "Widget Context" easier to me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a plugin I just published called the [Graceful Sidebar Plugin](http://mlynn.org/graceful-sidebar-plugin).  This enables you to create custom content for each page or post.  You simply create two custom fields in the page or post called "graceful_title" and "graceful_content" and drag the graceful sidebar widget to your theme's sidebar.

Comment: I've used all of the plugins recommended here and I have to say, yours is a pretty good alternative, when you just want a bit of sidebar content to be associated with a given page.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [Display Widgets](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/display-widgets/), it gives you a drop down list with the pages and other areas that you want your widget(s) to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the tutorial you linked to is for the Genesis Framework.  If using Genesis, you can use [Simple Sidebars](http://www.studiopress.com/plugins/simple-sidebars).